# Send form input by email without server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, email

For a locally hosted HTML page, I need to email a bit of user input (name, email, comments).

This is done on a touchscreen display, where visitors can leave their information and comments.

So I was thinking of using a virtual keyboard such as [here](http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/).

```
<form action="post" id="emails" onsubmit="return false;">
<input type="text" id="keyboard" placeholder="Enter name..."></input>
<input type="text"  id="keyboard2" placeholder="Enter email..."></input>
<input type='submit' id='send' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

I used this to be able to send the email [link](https://medium.com/design-startups/b53319616782).

And with the correct details, the following code works and I get emails in my inbox.

```
$('#send').click(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
        data: {
            'key': "xxxxxxxx",
            'message': {
            'from_email': "xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com",
            'to': [
            {
            'email': "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com",
            'name': 'xxxxxx',
            'type': 'to'
            }
            ],
            'autotext': 'true',
            'subject': 'TEST! TEST!',
            'html': 'test'
            }
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert("You send an email!"); // if you're into that sorta thing
    });
});
```

So this works, as in it sends the email with the text put in here: `'html': 'test'`

And instead of 'test', I would obviously like to get 'name + email'.

(Also it is probably for less then 50 emails per month, so just an email will suit my needs for now, nothing with databases and saving all this data. I would just like to get the email.)

So, is it possible and how should I do this?

Is the route I took now doable or would you suggest a completely different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// do everything inside after page load.
$(function() {
    $('#send').click(function() {
        // get values of inputs...
        var name = $('#keyboard').val(),
            email = $('#keyboard2').val();

        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
            data: {
                'key': "xxxxxxxx",
                'message': {
                'from_email': "xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com",
                'to': [
                {
                'email': "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com",
                'name': 'xxxxxx',
                'type': 'to'
                }
                ],
                'autotext': 'true',
                'subject': 'TEST! TEST!',
                'html': 'Name: ' + name + '\nEmail: ' + email // and use it!
                }
            }
        }).done(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            alert("You send an email!"); // if you're into that sorta thing
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I've altered my code to match this but when I press the send button after I filled in a random name + email I recieve an email containing only this: Name: Email:

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working now with the following code:

```
$(function() {

$('#send').click(function() {
    var name = $('#keyboard').val();
    var email = $('#keyboard2').val();
    $.ajax({ 
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',
        data: {
            'key': "xxxxxxxx",
            'message': {
            'from_email': "xxxxxx@xxxxxx.com",
            'to': [
            {
            'email': "xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxxxx.com",
            'name': 'xxxxxx',
            'type': 'to'
            }
            ],
            'autotext': 'true',
            'subject': 'TEST! TEST!',
            'html': 'Name: ' + name + '\nEmail: ' + email // and use it!
            }
        }
    }).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        alert("You send an email!"); // if you're into that sorta thing
    });
  });
});
```

On other simular problems were value were not shown I read something about the `.val()` was taking the values on page load (makes sense now), so I moved them down into the click function and it gives me the result I was after.

Comment: For me to get it working I had to place the ' var name = $('#keyboard').val();
    var email = $('#keyboard2').val(); ' lines inside the click function instead of above the function.